# Navigating Views Backbone does not remove model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The problem is reproduced in the following way:

1. Navigate to route[image: Initial State]
2. Navigate away [image: Go to other route]
3. Navigate back [image: Go back]

Whenever I navigate back the models aren't rendered. I suppose that is because this events aren't triggered:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.addAll);
```

This is my router:

```
    routes: {
        ''               : 'home',
        'home'           : 'home',
        'departments'    : 'departments',
        ...
    },

    home: function(){
        var view = new app.HomeView();
        this.showView(view);
    },

    departments: function(){
        var view = new app.DepartmentsView();
        this.showView(view);
    }, 
    showView: function(view){
         if (this.currentView){
          this.currentView.clean();
        }

        this.currentView = view;
        this.currentView.render()

        $('#container').html(this.currentView.el);
    }
```

And this is my clean method:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.clean = function () {
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
    _.each(this.subViews, function(subView){
        subView.clean();
        if(subView.onClose){ subView.onClose() }
    });
};
```

This is the onClose method on subviews:

```
onClose: function(){
        this.model.off('change',this.render);
        this.model.off('destroy',this.remove);
        console.log('unbinding');
    }
```

I save all subviews on array and then close when navigating away. I really haven't identified the root cause of such problem.

I'm quite desperate because I have tried everything from Derick Bailey's posts and going through Backbone's docs and haven't been able to fix this.

------EDIT--------
The view is composed as:

1. Parent View: Containing a the table, header, without the rows.
2. Child View: Which are the rows --> `<tr>`
3. Modal View: This is a
   view containing the form that creates the models

This is my repo if you want to take a look. Reproducing something minimal actually is a lot of code to post in a question. [REPO](https://github.com/DiegoGallegos4/HRM_NH)

Ill appreciate help with this.

Comment: When you navigate away,the models should be removed right..? Why are they still there..? Where are they created..? Who all are referencing them..?

Comment: I edited the question. If you wish you can see the repo under the app/scripts files. For this example, check departmentsView--> Parent View, departmentView--> Rows, departmentModalView --> Modal. The router is under routers folders and  my clean method under main.js.

Comment: Diego. Can you confirm if the models are in the collection, when you navigate to the Departments page the second time?

Comment: Yes, the collection is still there with the models, just checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what i suspect the problem is. Your `Departments` collection is only instantiated once, `app.Departments = new DepartmentList();`. Then in your `DepartmentsView` init function, you assign `this.collection = app.Departments;` This means that the second time you route to `DepartmentsView`, you're assigning its collection to an existing collection, that already has models. When you call `fetch()`, Backbone detects there are no new models (since you already have the models in the collection), and thus doesn't trigger the add events.

One thing you can do is call fetch with reset, `fetch({reset:true})`. Then when the fetch succeeds, it'll clear the existing models and re-add them all, and trigger reset.

Reset is a bit wasteful since you already have the models. Another solution is to check if the collection contains any models in your init function, if it does then render them. Something like this

```
initialize: function(){
        this.collection = app.Departments;
        this.subViews = [];

        if(this.collection.size() > 0)
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.addAll);

        this.collection.fetch();
    },
```

Then the fetch will add any new models it finds upon fetch success.

EDIT: Not the cleanest solution but it should work.

```
initialize: function(){
        this.collection = app.Departments;
        this.subViews = [];

        if(this.collection.size() > 0)
            this.preExisting = true;

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.addAll);

        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template({title: 'Departamentos',header_fields: this.tableHeader}) );
        this.$tbody = this.$('#rows');

        if(this.preExisting)
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);

        return this;
    },
```

Comment: Eric the first solution works for me. The second solution didn't work but is one that I prefer. On the department view the models are render on $('#rows') but I come back for the second time the console says that it is undefined. What can be the issue here?

Comment: I see. `$('#rows')` only exists after `render()` is called. And my solution is trying to insert rows before `render()`. To be honest I can't give you a clean solution. In my backbone code, creating views also creates a new collection, so I haven't dealt with your kind of problem before. You're going to have to detect pre-existing models (which i've already done with `if(this.collection.size() > 0)`, but then defer adding the views until after `render()` has been called. I can edit my answer to show you a naive solution.

Comment: When you create a view, you pass the collection to the view? All of this happens in the router right?